# Cloudflare Nginx SSL Not Trusted/400 bad request (No required ssl certificate was sent)

Tags: ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate, cloudflare

Similar to this the error I am receiving from this thread (https://community.cloudflare.com/t/getting-400-bad-request-no-required-ssl-certificate-was-sent-using-nginx-and-cloudflare-authenticated-origin-pulls/43276/4)

I am having trouble setting up Nginx to use my valid SSL certificate.

I have enabled authenticated origin pulls, and toggled it on and off before, and tried both ways, to no avail. My Nginx conf looks like this:

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;

ssl_ciphers EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/dh2048_param.pem;

ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;

ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/vendify-ssl-certificate.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/vendify-ssl-private-key.pem;
ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/vendify-CA-CF-Cert.pem;
```

Now, when I go to the site, the SSL is insecure, because it cannot be verified and trusted.

Then when I add this line to the bottom of the conf file, I get error 400 bad request (No required ssl certificate was sent)

```
ssl_verify_client on;
```

Again, I have enabled authenticated origin pulls, so I am not too sure what is going on.

Thanks!